# Adding or deleting widgets in my Wordpress footer is being mirrored in my sidebars

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer, sidebar

I'm not sure if anybody has experienced this issue before or if it is a common thing, but it seems my Wordpress footer and sidebar widget areas are linked somehow. When i add a widget to Sidebar Area 1, the same widget appears in Footer Area 1. And when i delete a widget from the footer, it is deleted from the sidebar. Strangely, the same is happening with footer area 2/sidebar area 2, and footer area 3/sidebar area 3.

Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

To show widget you first need register sidebar area for it by these part of code.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Test sidebar',
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    ));
}
```

Then you can display new sidebar anywhere in your templates by these part of code.

```
dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-1');
```

In your case it seems to me that in a footer and sidebar templates you use the same sidebar.

Check it in templates of your theme that produce footer and sidebar code. It can be  footer.php and sidebar.php templates.